# Running Gunicorn and Django

Tags: django, gunicorn

I don't know how to use gunicorn with django. Could you give me some help?

This is how I run the server with django. It is https

```
python3 manage.py runsslserver xx.8x.x3.x4:443 --certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/callservicesvps.online/fullchain.pem --key /etc/letsencrypt/live/callserv.com/privkey.pem
```

And in the gunicorn documentation it is mentioned that it must be executed as follows:

```
gunicorn myproject.wsgi
```

And here I have 2 questions. **What is myproject.wsgi?** **Where Can I find it?** Because if I look in the directory where the django project is, the only thing I find with wsgi is a file called wsgi.py

Running the server as follows gives me an error

```
gunicorn /home/proyectdirectory/wsgi.py
```

It also gives me an error if I put:

```
gunicorn /home/proyectdirectory/wsgi:Some_directory_where_the_proyec_is
```

Answer (score 3):

### What is myproject.wsgi?

`myproject.wsgi` IS the `wsgi.py` file you have located inside your project.

[End of answer]

*But a further explanation will clear up why this is..*

I imagine most people will look at`myproject.wsgi` and see a file with an extension file type `.wsgi` but this is just because of the way importing of `modules` is written in python.

I want to clarify what a `module` and a `package` before continuing an explanation.

#### What is a Module

[From the jargon heavy python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html)

> A module is a file containing Python definitions and statements.

Put simply, a `module` in python is just a python file containing any sort of functions, variables, or classes etc.

#### What is a Package

A package is just a collection of modules. The most simplest example, a special directory containing python files. In order to tell python that a directory is a package it must have a file named `__init__.py` inside of it. You will find a few of these inside different directories inside your django project. This is why they are there.

Now, I can say what I want to say which is the structure of the module namespace in python.

```py
package.subpackage.module
```

If you look inside your `wsgi.py` file you'll see a good example of importing from django's own `wsgi` module.

```py
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', '<project>.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

More specifically

```py
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
```

If you look inside the `django` package you can see how this works.
`django` (package) `core` (subpackage) `wsgi` (module)

[image: location of wsgi application import]

Remember, the command `gunicorn myproject.wsgi` should be run inside the base directory of your django project. I always remember this as the directory containing the `manage.py` file. That is how `gunicorn` can find the `wsgi.py` file using the module namespace in this way. `gunicorn` is written in python afterall.

`gunicorn /home/proyectdirectory/wsgi.py` will error because python module imports don't contain `/` and even if you tried `gunicorn home.proyectdirectory.wsgi` home and proyectdirectory are not python packages.

Now hopefully this makes sense:

"If `gunicorn myproject.wsgi` is referring to the `wsgi.py` file why not just put `gunicorn myproject.wsgi.py`?"

You can't put a `.py` extension because this will refer to a module inside the `wsgi` subpackage with a filename `py.py`!

Comment: Thanks for the answer Danoram. Do you know how to configure in gunicorn the server ip and the server port?

Comment: `gunicorn --bind <ip>:<port> <project_name>.wsgi`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. The last question is: How can I set that the communication is on Https with a SSL certificate? I do not know how to do it with gunicorn. With runsslserver I use the commands: runsslserver xx.8x.x3.x4:443 --certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/callservicesvps.online/fullchain.pem --key /etc/letsencrypt/live/callserv.com/privkey.pem

Comment: I would recommend making a new question for that. ssl certs can be tricky and I'm sure you'll get more answers that way